# Android server time

Tags: java, android, time

Could you tell me whats wrong here. The TextView always returns nothing.
I neither get the Exception nor the time.
I have also checked wether the time server works and it does.
Please help me. I have been despairing for days now.

```
 TextView zeit;
public static final String TIME_SERVER = "nist1-macon.macon.ga.us";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vorbereitung);

    zeit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zeit);


    try {
        zeit.setText(Long.toString(getCurrentNetworkTime()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        zeit.setText(e.getMessage());
    }


}






public static long getCurrentNetworkTime() throws Exception{
    NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
    TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
    long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();



    return returnTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

```
try {
    zeit.setText(String.valueOf(getCurrentNetworkTime()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    zeit.setText(e.getMessage());
}
```

The `String` class has a `static` method `valueOf()` which accepts a long and converts it to a `String`.

Comment: @SammySawischa did you tried to debug your code? does your method getCurrentNetworkTime() returns the desired value?

Comment: where do i have to look while debugging

Comment: check what your getCurrentNetworkTime() returns by debugging or logging